# Which Events are Covered in All Four Gospel Accounts?

Tags: bible, gospels

I have in mind to make two unified Gospel accounts as a project to help me focus on the essential aspects of the Life, Ministry,and Atonement of Jesus Christ.  For the first, I want to draw from events covered in 2 or more of the Gospel accounts.  And in the second those found in all four Gospels.

Once the information is in hand the idea is to use the most detailed account of an event and add any omitted details from the other accounts to fill in the full picture of what happened, and in what context.

Also any recommendations as to what translation/s to use would be helpful. My current list of candidate translations are: KJV, RSV(or ASV), NASB, NRSV & NIV. The first two are (in the U.S.) public domain translations so wouldn't be a challenge if interest developed in others receiving a copy.  Whereas the last two are more up to date in the textual research behind them; but are under copyright.

Thank you for any helpful information or suggestions  you may provide.

Comment: We are supplied, by Divine initiative and arrangement, with four accounts, each focussed on an aspect of Jesus' ministry. Had we needed a merging of all four, no doubt we would have been granted such. Merging the distinct accounts loses the structure and content needed to convey Christ in each of the four essential ways needed by our faith to lay hold upon Him as Messiah and King, Apostle, Saviour and God.

Comment: I recommend highly Orville E. Daniel's "A Harmony of the Four Gospels" in the NIV. His harmony is not your typical harmony. In bold print it even gives you a continuous narrative across all four Gospels, which includes the unique details of each Gospel writer. For example, "One Sabbath Jesus was going through the grainfields, and as his disciples walked along, they [Mark] were hungry and began [Matthew] to pick some heads of [Mark] grain, rub them in their hands and eat the kernels [Luke]. (Evidently, John did not include this story at all in his account.)

Comment: I believe the better approach is to start with Mark and add Matthew. Then add Luke to the Mark-Matthew and John to the Mark-Matthew-Luke. I recommend taking the approach of literal truth. If any account has something which cannot be reconciled, consider it a different event. Questions for reconciliation. 1) Can the event be repeated? Eg teaching on the Sabbath. If so, which occurred first? 2) Did the same event last long enough for one to occurred before the other? 3) If short and unrepeatable, are there different perspectives? Example the baptism as told from pov of Jesus, John, crowd.

Comment: Revelation Lad, I agree your approach has merit.  There was a time I was going to create a Harmony of the Gospels.  But so many before me have done this to great effect I found no need to repeat their work.

Comment: Nigel J,  I have no interest in trying to create an edition of the 4 Gospels that would replace their use in my life or anyone else's.  Simply a project to help me focus on the essentials of the Gospel message.

Comment: rhetorician, thank you hindly for the book suggestion. I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 3):

The only major event prior to passion week that is found in all 4 Gospels is the feeding of the 5000 (Matthew 14:13–21; Mark 6:31–44; Luke 9:12–17; John 6:1–14).

Jesus' baptism by John is implied in the Gospel of John, but it is only explicit in the Synoptics.

Multiple events of passion week are found in all 4 Gospels, including the triumphal entry, the betrayal, the crucifixion, and the resurrection.

Comment: +1 The feeding of the 5,000 is in all four but they may not be describing the same event. There are differences which some see that may not be reconcilable. If that is the case, the resolution is to see Jesus fed 5,000 on more than one occasion.

Comment: I'll note there are books written on this. A quick comparison can be found [here](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/harmony?lang=eng) and if un-interested in LDS perspective ignore scriptures under `Latter-day Revelation`. Everything else is from KJV and should match up

Comment: Revelation Lad, agreed, there is evidence to suggest there was two separate occasions where Christ fed large crowds,  Still, the fact much of the narrative is similar, and all 4 Gospels include a narrative of feeding a large crowd does lend the occurrence/s an importance.  However, Much less important than the Crucifixion or Resurrection.